# Does positive definiteness imply $x^{T}Mx \geq \alpha x^{T}x$ for some $\alpha > 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I require an $n \times n$ matrix to satisfy $x^{T}Mx \geq \alpha x^{T}x$ for some $\alpha > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $x \geq 0$ (1).

Is it sufficient to show that M is positive definite (such that 
$x^{T}Mx > 0$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$)?
If not, what additional properties should matrix M satisfy for this property (1) to hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha$ can be taken to be the lowest eigenvalue of $M$.  Observe that $M$ has a full set of orthonormal eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, hence any $x$ can be written as $x=c_1v_1+\ldots+c_nv_n$ and we can compute

$$
x^TMx= c_1^2\lambda_1+\ldots+c_n^2\lambda_n\geq \lambda_{min}||x||^2.
$$

Comment: I assume you've made use of the (real version of) spectral theorem here, but that only applies when $M$ is assumed to be symmetric as well. So how can we justify the existence of orthogonal basis of eigenvectors in the non symmetric case?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Given what OP was asking for, this answer is justified for symmetric positive definite matrices.  For non-symmetric matrices, the best you can do is to use the singular value decomposition $M = U\Sigma V^T$.  Here we will have $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal of different dimensions, and $\Sigma$ will be non-square but will have non-negative entries along its main diagonal.  We refer to the columns of $U$ and $V$ as the **left and right singular vectors** (respectively) of $M$.  Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Comment: right that's what I expected for non-symmetric matrices. but having had time to think about this, i believe a simple compactness and homogeneity argument (on the unit sphere) can establish the result in question, even without symmetry of $M$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Well, I think there's an important issue here: how do you define inner product?  If $M$ is $m\times n$ it's not possible to compute $x^TMx$ for any vector $x$ unless $m=n$.

Comment: the question assumes $m=n$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Sorry, it's been a long day and I mistook "non symmetric" and "non square" to be synonymous for a sec.  I suppose another way would be to just project to the symmetric part of the matrix $\frac{1}{2}\left (M + M^T\right )$ and use the argument above as well.  Maybe you want to post a separate question?  People might have good input.

Comment: It's all good now. I was merely confused for a second as to whether you've implicitly assumed symmetry of the matrix $M$; my further comments were just to show that it is possible to prove this claim even without assuming symmetry or making use of linear algebra; and that a purely topological/analytical proof was available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, positive definiteness implies that $x^{T}Mx \geq \alpha x^{T}x$ for some $\alpha > 0$.

In particular, the [Rayleigh Ritz theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) tells us that if $M$ is symmetric, then we have $x^{T}Mx \geq \alpha x^{T}x$ for $\alpha = \min_{x \neq 0} \frac{x^TMx}{x^Tx} = \lambda_{\min}(M)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be positive definite. Let $\{e_i\}_i$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $M$ and let $\alpha_i$ be the corresponding eigenvalues, which are positive since $M$ is positive definite.
Then any $x$ can be written as
$$ x = \sum_i x_i e_i. $$
Thus
$$x^T M x = \sum_{ij} x_ix_j \; e_i^T M e_j = \sum_{ij} x_ix_j \alpha_j \; e_i^Te_j = \sum_j \alpha_j x_j^2 \geq \alpha x^T x $$
where $\alpha = \min(\alpha_i)$.